# Rspec overriding Capybara 'within' method in Cucumber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, cucumber, capybara

I am testing the creation of an account on a large consumer website using cucumber and capybara. When I run my capybara code in a regular pry session it all works. But when I run the cucumber test, the `within` block doesn't seem to run and the sign up form doesn't get filled out.

`env.rb`

```
require 'capybara/cucumber'
require 'selenium-webdriver'

Before do
  Capybara.default_driver = :selenium
end
```

`test.feature`

```
Scenario: Test consumer site account creation
* I create a new example.com account
```

`step_definition.rb`

```
When(/^I create a new account$/) do
  visit 'http://example.com/myaccount'
  find("#cboxClose").click if page.has_css?("#cboxClose")

  require 'pry';binding.pry
  within("form[name='newCustomer']") do
    random_letters = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(5)
    fill_in "Email Address", :with => "test-#{random_letters}@example.com"
    fill_in "Create Password", :with => "Password123"
    fill_in "Confirm Password", :with => "Password123"
    click_on "Create Account"
  end
end
```

When I run `cucumber` and try to run the `within` block in pry, I get this:

```
#<RSpec::Matchers::AliasedMatcher:0x007ff5e86b16e8
 @base_matcher=
  #<RSpec::Matchers::BuiltIn::BeWithin:0x007ff5e86b1710
   @delta="form[name='newCustomer']">,
 @description_block=
  #<Proc:0x007ff5e4c34d08@/Users/anthonychung/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rspec-expectations-3.2.0/lib/rspec/matchers.rb:245 (lambda)>>
```

So I suspect RSpec's aliased matcher is overriding capybara's within method somehow.

When I try to do `within(:css, "form[etc.]")` I get an argument error `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
page.within
```

I feel so dumb but at least I figured it out.